# Replacing some uppercase character with lowercase character using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file named `file.txt` that contains absolute paths. It looks like that:

```
J:/Folder/inner
J:/Folder/inner2
```

First, I wanted to write a bash script that replaces the `J:/` with `/cygdrive/j/`. So I did it like this:

```
sed -i 's/J:\//\/cygdrive\/j\//g' file.txt
```

and it works as expected.
But now I want something more complicated: the absolute paths don't have to start with `J`- they can start with `C`, `D`, `E` ...
I want to do the same thing as I did above, just that I don't know what will be the first letter. For example: `C:/Folder/inner` will become `/cygdrive/c/Folder/inner` and `D:/Folder/inner` will become `/cygdrive/d/Folder/inner`.
I understand that I need to use regular expression for acheiving that, but I have not found the way to do this. Do you know how can I get what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it with `sed`, you'd need support for changing case which `GNU sed` provides. So, this would not be a portable solution

```
$ cat file.txt 
J:/Folder/inner
J:/Folder/inner2
C:/Folder/inner
D:/Folder/inner

$ sed -E 's#^(.):#/cygdrive/\l\1#' file.txt 
/cygdrive/j/Folder/inner
/cygdrive/j/Folder/inner2
/cygdrive/c/Folder/inner
/cygdrive/d/Folder/inner
```

- `-E` to enable ERE, in this case avoids having to escape the `()`

  - some versions might support `-r` only instead of `-E`
- `^(.):` match a character and `:` from beginning of line

  - use `^([A-Z]):` or `^([A-Za-z]):` as needed to match only alphabets
- `/cygdrive/\l\1` in replacement section, the string `/cygdrive/` and lowercase version of captured character will be used
- Note the use of `#` as delimiter character, helps to avoid escaping `/`s in search/replacement sections

  - any character other than `\` and newline character can be used
- add `-i` once the solution is working as expected

Answer (score 4):

I would use `Awk` to solve this using the `tolower()` for lower-case conversion and print the rest of the fields using the field separator set to `:`

```
awk -F: '{print "/cygdrive/"tolower($1)""$2}' file.txt
```

which basically means print the `$1` value after lower-casing it (`J`) and append `$2` after it (rest of the string). The `""` just signifies an empty string without any character present. You can remove them also.

Once you find the names are replaced properly, change the source file itself

```
awk -F: '{print "/cygdrive/"tolower($1)""$2}' file.txt > temp && mv temp file.txt
```

On a sample file as below

```
J:/Folder/inner
J:/Folder/inner2
C:/Folder/inner
D:/Folder/inner
```

the command produces an output file as

```
/cygdrive/j/Folder/inner
/cygdrive/j/Folder/inner2
/cygdrive/c/Folder/inner
/cygdrive/d/Folder/inner
```

---

Another variant in `perl` if you have it installed,

```
perl -lne 'print "/cygdrive/\L$1$2" if /(.):(.+)/' file.txt
```

Comment: Tried it now- I get the following errors running those scripts: awk:'{print. 
awk: ^invalid char ''' in expression.

Comment: Which version of `Awk` are you using? Can you output `awk --version`?

Comment: Version: Gnu Awk 3.1.6

Comment: @Mark: I checked it working fine before posting it here. How are you executing the command on the terminal?

Comment: I execute those lines in the shell. I'm working on cygwin if it matters

Comment: @Mark: Beware of the DOS unicode quotes, Use proper shell quotes. If you could add a screeshot uploaded somewhere and link it here

Comment: @Mark: That is exactly the problem I stated in previous comment,  `‘’` are unicode quoted which won't work in `bash` shell, Use the shell quotes `''` around Awk

Comment: Why two quotes before $2 ?

Comment: @123: Thanks! Added a note that it can be removed too!

Comment: I tried writing the awk line in a script file. I got the following error: 0 is invalid as number of arguments for toLower